# How to force the compiler to show warning messages?

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

Writing the following code...

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myContext.xml");
```

...will force eclipse to show the this warning

```
Resource leak: 'applicationContext' is never closed
```

This is because that I should call `applicationContext.close()`

How can I do that myself ? How can I instruct the user that he should call a specific method **before** or **after** using objects instantiated from the classes that I wrote ?

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I do that myself?"? From your question title I thought you wanted the same warnings when compiling via console.

Comment: What do you mean by instruct the user? Who's the user? And if you can give more detail on the specifics of the project that would help a lot. Are you making a compiler? a GUI? an IDE? something else?

Comment: I don't think it is a compiler warning. Do you use some code checking plugins like findbugs?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, so when I wrote the code I mentioned, Eclipse showed the mentioned warning message. So I wanted to instruct the user, as Eclipse instructed me through a warning, to do whatever the class writer thinks must me done to use the class correctly. Thanks to Joop, he said that this is a feature specific to Java 7 and the implemented interface `AutoCloseable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that in general. What you saw was the try-with-resources functionality of Java 7.

```
public class MyClose implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

Fine:

```
try (MyClass x = new MyClass()) {
    ...

} // Automatic close
```

Fine too:

```
MyClass x = null;+
try {
    x = new MyClass();
    ...
} finally {
    x.close();
}
```

Warning:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
...
```

It is the `AutoCloseable` that leads the IDE to attend for a missing `close()/try`.
One of the reasons is that clicking on the warning probably proposes to repair it with a try-with-resources (in some IDEs).

---

***However there is a code design pattern***

```
class ServiceBaseClass {
    protected Z z;

    protected YourBaseClass() {
    }

    public final void process(X x) {
        z = ...;
        ...
        f(x, y);
        ...
        g(x);
    }

    protected void f(X x, Y y) {
    }

    protected void g(X x) {
        ... z ...
    }
}
```

Here one lets the child class implement (override) `f` and `g` - the requirements -, and takes care that the process logic is done oneself, in a public final `process` - the service -.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand what you're trying to say about the last example in your answer.

Comment: One may do the control flow and preparation of data oneself in a base class with a non-overridable function (`process` here) to call. The variable code then have to be given by the child class.